# Can Python's argparse permute argument order like gnu getopt?

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments, argparse, getopt

GNU getopt, and command line tools that use it, allow options and arguments to be interleaved, known as permuting options (see http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html#Using-Getopt). Perl's Getopt::Long module also supports this (with qw(:config gnu_getopt)). argparse seems to not support (or even mention) permuting options.

There are many SO questions related to arg/opt order, but none seem answer this question: Can argparse be made to permute argument order like getopt?

The use case is a prototypical command line signature like GNU sort:

```
sort [opts] [files]
```

in which 1) options and files are permuted, and 2) the file list may contain zero or more arguments.

For example:

```
import argparse
p = argparse.ArgumentParser();
p.add_argument('files',nargs='*',default=['-']);
p.add_argument('-z',action='store_true')

p.parse_args(['-z','bar','foo']) # ok
p.parse_args(['bar','foo','-z']) # ok
p.parse_args(['bar','-z','foo']) # not okay
usage: ipython [-h] [-z] [files [files ...]]
```

I've tried:

- p.parse_known_args -- doesn't complain, but doesn't actually permute either and it doesn't balk about arguments that look like invalid options (e.g., --bogus or -b above).
- p.add_argument('files',nargs=argparse.REMAINDER) -- option -z is included in files unless before positional args
- p.add_argument('files',nargs='*',action='append');

I want to implement something close to the GNU sort prototype above. I am not interested in a flag that can be specified for each file (e.g., -f file1 -f file2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Python 3.7** adds support for this with "parse_intermixed_args" - see https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_intermixed_args

Answer (score 4):

Here's a quick solution which decodes the argument list one (options, positional arguments) pair at a time.

```
import argparse

class ExtendAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        items = getattr(namespace, self.dest, None)
        if items is None:
            items = []
        items.extend(values)
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, items)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('files', nargs='*', action=ExtendAction)
parser.add_argument('-z', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-v', action='count')
parser.add_argument('args_tail', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)

def interleaved_parse(argv=None):
    opts = parser.parse_args(argv)
    optargs = opts.args_tail
    while optargs:
        opts = parser.parse_args(optargs, opts)
        optargs = opts.args_tail
    return opts

print(interleaved_parse('-z bar foo'.split()))
print(interleaved_parse('bar foo -z'.split()))
print(interleaved_parse('bar -z foo'.split()))
print(interleaved_parse('-v a -zv b -z c -vz d -v'.split()))
```

Output:

```
Namespace(args_tail=[], files=['bar', 'foo'], v=None, z=True)
Namespace(args_tail=[], files=['bar', 'foo'], v=None, z=True)
Namespace(args_tail=[], files=['bar', 'foo'], v=None, z=True)
Namespace(args_tail=[], files=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], v=4, z=True)
```

Note: Don't try to use this with other non-flag arguments (besides a single `nargs='*'` argument and the `args_tail` argument). The parser won't know about previous invocations of `parse_args` so it will store the wrong value for these non-flag arguments. As a workaround, you can parse the `nargs='*'` argument manually after using `interleaved_parse`.

Comment: Py 3.7 adds a `parse_intermixed_args`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50916124/allow-positional-command-line-arguments-with-nargs-to-be-seperated-by-a-flag

Answer (score 3):

I've seen nothing definitive in the argparse documentation stating that it can or cannot permute.  Based on your own observations, where permutation failed, and the following doc quotes, I'm going to conclude it cannot be done.

1. There's already a module explicitly named '[getopt](http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html)':

   > Note The `getopt` module is a parser for command line options whose API
   >   is designed to be familiar to users of the C `getopt()` function. Users
   >   who are unfamiliar with the C `getopt()` function or who would like to
   >   write less code and get better help and error messages should consider
   >   using the `argparse` module instead.
2. Even the default for getopt does not permute, there's a more explicitly defined method named [`gnu_getopt()`](http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html#getopt.gnu_getopt):

   > This function works like `getopt()`, except that GNU style scanning mode
   >   is used by default. This means that option and non-option arguments
   >   may be intermixed.
3. In the getopt docs, the above reference to argparse is further exaggerated by the inclusion of the following:

   > Note that an equivalent command line interface could be produced with
   >   less code and more informative help and error messages by using the
   >   `argparse` module:

Again, nothing definitive, but, to me, a very sharp divide is being drawn between getopt and argparse with the documentation favoring/advocating argparse.

Here's an example using `gnu_getop()` which satifies your `-z [file [file]]` test:

```
>>> args = 'file1 -z file2'.split()
>>> args
['file1', '-z', 'file2']
>>> opts, args = getopt.gnu_getopt(args, 'z')
>>> opts
[('-z', '')]
>>> args
['file1', 'file2']
```

**Edit 1: Go Permute Yourself, with argparse**

Inspired by the definition of "permute" in the 'Using Getopt' page you linked to,

> The default is to permute the contents of argv while scanning it so
>   that eventually all the non-options are at the end.

how about permuting the arg string before passing it to `parse_args()`?

```
import argparse

p = argparse.ArgumentParser();
p.add_argument('files',nargs='*',default=['-']);
p.add_argument('-z',action='store_true')
```

Rolling your own:

```
import re

def permute(s, opts_ptn='-[abc]'):
    """Returns a permuted form of arg string s using a regular expression."""
    opts = re.findall(opts_ptn, s)
    args = re.sub(opts_ptn, '', s)
    return '{} {}'.format(' '.join(opts), args).strip()

>>> p.parse_args(permute('bar -z foo', '-[z]').split())
Namespace(files=['bar', 'foo'], z=True)
```

Leveraging getopt:

```
import getopt

def permute(s, opts_ptn='abc'):
    """Returns a permuted form of arg string s using `gnu_getop()'."""
    opts, args = getopt.gnu_getopt(s.split(), opts_ptn)
    opts = ' '.join([''.join(x) for x in opts])
    args = ' '.join(args)
    return '{} {}'.format(opts, args).strip()

>>> p.parse_args(permute('bar -z foo', 'z').split())
Namespace(files=['bar', 'foo'], z=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a method to provide multiple combined arguments to `argparse` like in a terminal. For example `ls -la` or `ps -aux`. However, I have tried a method that is somewhat similar to the terminal usage of arguments. Meaning the combined argument.

Sample Code: test.py

```py
import argparse 
from itertools import permutations 

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--image-dir', '-i', type=str, help='path to directory where the image files are presented', default=None)
parser.add_argument('--text-dir', '-t', type=str, help='path to directory where the text files are presented', default=None)
parser.add_argument('--json-dir', '-j', type=str, help='path to directory to save the generated json files', default=None)
parser.add_argument(*list(map(lambda x: '-' +''.join(x), permutations('it'))), dest='image_text_dir',type=str, help='combined path of image and text', default=None)
parser.add_argument(*list(map(lambda x: '-' +''.join(x), permutations('jt'))), dest='json_text_dir',type=str, help='combined path of json and text', default=None)
parser.add_argument(*list(map(lambda x: '-' +''.join(x), permutations('ji'))), dest='json_image_dir',type=str, help='combined path of image and json', default=None)
parser.add_argument(*list(map(lambda x: '-' +''.join(x), permutations('itj'))), dest='image_text_json_dir',type=str, help='combined path of image, text, and json', default=None)

parser.add_argument('--verbose', '-v', action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()

image_dir = vars(args)['image_dir']
txt_dir = vars(args)['text_dir']
json_dir = vars(args)['json_dir']
verbose = vars(args)['verbose']
image_text_dir = vars(args)['image_text_dir']
json_text_dir = vars(args)['json_text_dir']
json_image_dir = vars(args)['json_image_dir']
image_text_json_dir = vars(args)['image_text_json_dir']

if image_text_dir:
    image_dir = txt_dir = image_text_dir
if json_text_dir:
    json_dir = txt_dir = json_text_dir
if json_image_dir:
    json_dir = image_dir = json_image_dir
if image_text_json_dir:
    image_dir = txt_dir = json_dir = image_text_json_dir

print(f'Image {image_dir}, Text {txt_dir}, and json {json_dir}')
```

Now in your terminal, you can run the file as:

```bash
name@hostname:~$ py test.py -ijt ./path/to/file
Image ./path/to/file, Text ./path/to/file, and json ./path/to/file
```

Or,

```bash
name@hostname:~$ py test.py -ij ./path/to/file
Image ./path/to/file, Text None, and json ./path/to/file
```

I hope this is what you were seeking.