# Order of the arguments matters in getopt

Tags: python, getopt

My application parses the command line arguments:

```
import sys
import getopt

arguments = sys.argv[1:]
options, remainder = getopt.getopt(arguments, "aa:bb:cc:dd:h", ["aaaa=", "bbbb=", "cccc=", "dddd=", "help"])

print dict(options)
```

This works great but at the same time odd: if I put the arguments in the different order, they aren't get parsed

```
python my_app.py --aaaa=value1 --bbbb=value2 --cccc=value3 --dddd=value4 #ok
python my_app.py --dddd=value4 --bbbb=value2 --cccc=value3 --aaaa=value1 # empty
```

That's disappointing because the order of the arguments shouldn't matter, should it? Is there any way to solve that?

UPDATE:

```
python my_app.py -aa value1 # odd, empty { "-a" : "" } 
python my_app.py -a value1 # even this empty { "-a" : "" }
```

Comment: works fine for me. How are you populating arguments?

Comment: What version of Python are you at?  If you have 3.2 or later, [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) is a good way to go, much more flexible than getopt.

Comment: @user3885927, I just showed you. What do you mean?

Comment: you don't show how sys.argv is read.

Comment: @user3885927, do you want me to show that? Ok, I'll show that. From the blackest part of my heart. Updated.

Comment: @Ajean `argparse` is in the 2.7 as well

Comment: @Ajean, optparse seems better.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp, although `optparse` is still available, it is planned to be deprecated, though a date was not yet set for this, as can be seen in [PEP 389](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0389/#deprecation-of-optparse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the first comment to your question, your main example regarding failed parsing of arguments in a different order works just fine:

```
~/tmp/so$ python my_app.py --aaaa=value1 --bbbb=value2 --cccc=value3 --dddd=value4
{'--aaaa': 'value1', '--cccc': 'value3', '--dddd': 'value4', '--bbbb': 'value2'}
~/tmp/so$ python my_app.py --dddd=value4 --bbbb=value2 --cccc=value3 --aaaa=value1
{'--cccc': 'value3', '--bbbb': 'value2', '--aaaa': 'value1', '--dddd': 'value4'}
```

If that's not the case for you, please update the script to print the remainder as well, and show its output.

However, you have still misused the `getopt` library and that's the reason the latest examples you provided don't work as expected. You can't specify more than a single character as an option, since the second character would count as a new separate option. `getopt` provides no way to differentiate between two consecutive characters that count as a single option (with the first one carrying no argument value, as it is not followed by a colon) or a single option that is composed of two characters. From [`getopt.getopt`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html#getopt.getopt), with my added emphasis:

> options is the string of option **letters** that the script wants to recognize, with options that require an argument followed by a colon.

Therefore, when `getopt` parses your arguments, each time it encounters a `-a` argument, it associates it with the first `a` option it notices, which in your case is not followed by a colon. Thus, it sets this option, discards its argument value, if there was any (if `-aa` was passed as an argument to the script, the second `a` counts as the argument value) and moves on to the next argument.

Finally, regarding `getopt` and [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html). [The documentation clearly advocates `argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html):

> The getopt module is a parser for command line options whose API is designed to be familiar to users of the C getopt() function. Users who are unfamiliar with the C getopt() function or who would like to write less code and get better help and error messages should consider using the argparse module instead.

More about why `argparse` is better than both `getopt` and the deprecated `optparse` can be read in [this PEP](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0389/#why-aren-t-getopt-and-optparse-enough) and in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3217673/3903832).
The only functionality that I've found to be supported in `getopt` while it requires a bit of work in `argparse` is argument order permutation like that of `gnu getopt`. However, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9537510/3903832) explains how this can be achieved via `argparse`.